# How to make a UIView that can cover the navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to show the `UIView` in full screen, but show the status bar, other things, like the  navigation bar need to cover by the `UIView`.

**How can I do that ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struggling a little to fully understand the question, but I think you're asking how you can display a `UIView` above another view (so that the view with the navigation controls is completely hidden by the second view)?

`UIViewController` has:

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

It would be wise to have your second view managed by a `UIViewController`, too. For the sake of example let's say your view with the navigation bar is managed by `UINavigationViewController`, and the view you want to display is managed by `otherViewController`...

```
[navigationViewController presentModalViewController:otherViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have a view that is a UIView, call "mainUIView", and a UIView called "subUIView", and I want the subUIView fill in the screen, except the status bar.

Comment: OK, two choices - Use UIViewControllers and present/display as appropriate, or add subUIView as a subview of mainUIView or your application's UIWindow directly (as suggested by Eiko below).

Both will work, but without understanding more of your use case, I couldn't say which is better/more appropriate.

Answer (score 64):

I believe what he was asking was how to make a UIView cover the entire screen (sort of like custom pop up). This is precisely how I ended up here. So I will offer my solution. Call this function anywhere.

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:yourUIView];
```

Here the view you introduced cover over the whole screen unlike

```
[self.view addSubview:yourUIView];
```

Whereby, the navigation bar is uncovered.

Comment: Thanks byte..It helped me..I was trying to add the view in navigtionBar of the navigationController..It did not allow user interaction..but when I did as you have mentioned, it works as expected..

Comment: This was really helpful for me . is it possible to add an animation. like a silding down animation

Comment: @Mr.G Just offset the frame of `yourUIView` and use `UIView` method `+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations`

Comment: @Byte thanks for the reply . i managed to do it. once again thanks :>

Comment: This works on iOS 7 and iOS 8. On iOS 9 a keyboard dismiss event will remove the view from the hierarchy. ex. Showing an alert styled view and triggering the keyboard to dismiss in the background.

Comment: This point [self.navigationController.view addSubview:yourUIView] helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Add the view to your main UIWindow instance directly as a subview.

Answer (score 1):

I know the OP was looking for a way to cover the navigation bar totally, but instead of covering it, you  could just temporarily hide it.  Once hidden, you can add you view as a subView and change its frame or constraints so it takes up the whole screen.

```
- (void)showViewOverNavBar:(UIView *)view {

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```