# UIView above NavigationBar and StatusBar

Tags: swift, uiview, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I need to show UIView with full screen mode above NavigationBar and StatusBar
How i can do that?

---

P.S. Sorry for my English

[image: View above NavigationBar and StatusBar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code will help you with that. You can change the color to your desired color to achieve the desired affect.

```
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];

UIView *blue = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[blue setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[window addSubview: blueView];
```

Swift Code:

```
if let applicationDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate? {
   if let window:UIWindow = applicationDelegate.window {
      let blueView:UIView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
      blueView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
      window.addSubview(blueView)
   }
}
```

Comment: @Eric Aya I added the swift version of the code. Thanks for suggestion :). Feel free to comment if there's anything more that can be done

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this persons answer.

[How to make a UIView that can cover the navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511220/how-to-make-a-uiview-that-can-cover-the-navigation-bar)

Basically, instead of setting your 2nd view as a subview of your main view, set the 2nd view as a subview of your navigation controller.